# Media Query to Hide Icon when on desktop and laptop only

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a clickable icon image in the header of my web page; I want to hide the icon image when the page is pulled up on a desktop, laptop, and/or any larger screens. However, I want the icon to show when the page is pulled up on a mobile device/ phones and hand-held tablets.

This is what I tried:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  .ghost {
    margin-left: 500px;
    /*show the icon on smaller screen*/
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .ghost {
    margin-left: 500px;
    display: none;
    /*hide the icon on larger screens*/
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

/* Adding this so the demo is visible even though the image link is broken. --editor */
.ghost img { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()" class="ghost"><img src="img/ic_ghost.svg" alt="ghost" /></div>
```

...could I get some help with this please? ...thanks

Comment: Looks like the icon will be visible on screens bigger than 1024px. Try a bigger max-width on your second media query?

Comment: Did you clear browser cache? `Ctrl + Shift + R` or manually in browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

#### *Hi*

If you want to display icon JUST on <= 700px devices your code should look like this below. Setting `min-width: 0px` in first @media and `max-width: 1024px` in second is unnecessary.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .ghost {
        margin-left: 500px;

    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 701px) {

    .ghost {
        margin-left: 500px;
        display: none; /* Acts like this item isn't there at all */
        visibility: hidden; /* Doesn't show the item, but saves space for it */
    }
}
```

I don't know your full issue, but if you want to act like it isn't there on large screens this CSS below will be better ;)

```
.ghost {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

    .ghost {
        margin-left: 500px;
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

---

More info about media queries you can find e.g. on this [W3Schools site](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

#### *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

You have to write only one media query. Like this

`@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {}`. It for mobile devices.

```css
.ghost { 
    display: block; /* default it will show in mobile devices. */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .ghost { 
    display: none; /* it will hide larger than 765px eg: laptop and desktop */
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()" class="ghost"><img src="img/ic_ghost.svg" alt="ghost" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard resolution for desktops is **1024px**.
For tablets, it is **768px** and for mobile it is **320px**;

So to hide the image for desktops and above, you could do the following:

```css
.ghost {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .ghost {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="openNav()" class="ghost"><img src="img/ic_ghost.svg" alt="ghost" /></div>
```